# Can I customize ispell to ignore environments

Tags: emacs, spellchecking

I've found a couple of answers about ignoring commands (environment variables `TEXSKIP1` and `TEXSKIP2` can contain commands with 1 resp 2 arguments -- how I wish there were a 3 variant!) but not about environments. Is that possible? Is there a spell checker (preferably inside emacs) that is more savvy about the structure of LaTeX documents?

Comment: Are you using AUCTeX for editing your .tex files or Emacs stock latex-mode?

Comment: @ArashEsbati Stock latex mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs comes with the library `ispell.el` which provides the variable `ispell-tex-skip-alists` for the purpose of skipping macro/environments and their arguments.  Say you have a macro `\mycommand` and you want to skip its 3 mandatory arguments and an environment `myverbatim` which you want to ignore completely, you'd write something like this in your init file:

```lisp
(let ((head (car ispell-tex-skip-alists))
      (tail (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
  (setq head (append '(("\\\\mycommand" ispell-tex-arg-end 3))
                     head))
  (setq tail (append '(("myverbatim" . "\\\\end{myverbatim}"))
                     tail))
  (setq ispell-tex-skip-alists (list head tail)))
```

`ispell-tex-arg-end` is a function also provided by `ispell.el`:

> `ispell-tex-arg-end` is a native-compiled Lisp function in `ispell.el`.
>
> `(ispell-tex-arg-end &optional ARG)`
>
> Skip across ARG number of braces.

Note that optional arguments before the mandatory ones are always ignored.

You can also have a look at this part of [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Selecting-a-Command.html#Selecting-a-Command) which describes this stuff in more detail.